# I am getting JSON data in a response back from the server. But how can I parse that data to show on the popup window

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

I am getting json data as a response back from the server. I want to parse this JSON data and embed all the data into a pop up window.

```
var on_show_info = function() {
                alert("aa");
                request_meta_info = $.ajax({
                url: data + info.id,
                type: 'GET',
                async: false,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: data,
                error: error    
        });
    };

var data = function(data, text_status, XMLHttpRequest) {

    alert(data);
    var html = '';
    var info = {};


    here I want that JSON parsing code as I am getting response back from the server in data field. Any help will be appreciated and I want to embed those parse data in to a popup window as shown below by this command `($('#popup-meta .popup-content').html(html);)`


    });

    $('#popup-meta').removeClass('waiting');
    $('#popup-meta .popup-content').html(html);
};
```

This is the response I am getting back from the server as JSON data just for an example..

```
jsonp13082({"responseHeader":{"status":0,"Time":3,"params":{"json.wrf":"jsonp13082","wt":"json","q":"8377"}},"response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[{"key":"83779616","number":"080","name":"Designated","name":"Non ","number":"27837","date":"2010-08-24T07:00:00Z","name":"Canada","name":"Application","title":"collision detection","date":"2008-03-03T08:00:00Z","id":"414","code":"CA","date":"2009-03-03T08:00:00Z","name":"Michael Henry","mgr_name":"William Henry","id":"79616","name":"oen","claims":"74","date":"2012-03-03T08:00:00Z","claims":"8","url":"","inventors":["D.","rshi","Pa"],"guid":["23","26","25"],"towners":["XYZ"],"inventors":["D","name2","name3"],"owners":["XYZ"]}]}})
```

Comment: ~please be clearer on what sort of data u are displaying. If u want the answer on how to appropriately display specific data

Comment: @pico.creator, I have updated the question.. In that I have included the JSON response that I am getting as an example just for one ID.

Comment: Seems to me like you are actually getting a jsonp response and you are expected to have a function 'jsonp130826....' which handles the response. Is the request actually going to a different domain? If not you don't need the response to be wrapped in a function call

Comment: @user519575, yes my resoponse in JSONP..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var dataObj = jQuery.parseJSON( jsonStr );
```

See the link for more on jQuery (which u included) and converting jsons to data format.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

How u use the data for the display is up to you and what data you are given.

You can use the jQuery native dialog box to display such a pop up

[dialog in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428896/dialog-in-jquery)

In which you can do a for loop to convert each parameter into a display via HTML formatting (possibly using HTML tables).

```
function tablefy( object ) {
var retStr = "";
var typeSet = typeof(object);
if( typeSet == 'object' ) {
    retStr += "<table>"
    for( x in object ) {
        retStr += "<tr>";
        retStr += "<td>";
        if( typeof( x ) == "string" ) {
            retStr += x;
        } else {
            retStr += x.toString();
        }
        retStr += "</td><td>";
        retStr += tablefy( object[x] );
        retStr += "</td>"
        retStr += "</tr>"
    }
    retStr += "</table>"
} else {
    //just dumps it raw
    if( typeSet == 'String' ) {
        return object;
    } 

    if( typeSet == 'number' ) {
        return object.toString();
    }

    if( typeSet == 'boolean') {
        if( object == true ) {
            return 'true';
        } else {
            return 'false';
        }
    }

    return 'null';

    }
}
return retStr;
}
```

Comment: I think you're heading down the wrong path here - if the response is valid json it should already be parsed so there will be no string

Comment: Good point, haha, nearly fogotten some of the wonders of jQuery :) oh well this is valid assuming he got it in a string format.

Comment: @pico.creator, I have updated the question and also I have included JSON response just for an example..

Comment: @Raihan jamal: Whoa that is a complicated chunk of data to display. So I'm assuming you want the API call for opening a "dialog window" displaying such data. Though the formatting have to be done on your own

Comment: @pico.creator, I want all the data starting from {"key":"83779616", and I have to show all these data in a popup window.
For Example like this:   and we keep on proceeding by this way
Reference Number:080879CA

Comment: @pico.creator, I have already open the popup window, I just want to extract the data so that I can easily put all the data with my formatting..

Comment: @Raihan: I don't think your response is json, see comment on your question

Comment: @Raihan jamal: Amyway i added a recursive function (code snippets). It is yet to be tested. But it gives you a rough idea on how to convert an object into a html format in which it can be displayed. Though i suggest you may want to custom code the whole thing urself, unless ur willing to use such a generic formatting.

Comment: @pico.creator, I was also trying to create table dynamically
and I am getting error:-syntax error on html+ = ["<table border ='1'>";]
  var html = "";
  var info = {};
  alert(data.response.docs[0].c_qc_guid);
  
  //var jsonObj = $.parseJSON(data);

  //alert(jsonObj.response.docs[0].c_application_number);
  html+ = "<table border ='1'>";
  html+ ="<tr>";
  html+ ="<td>"+document.write(data.response.docs[0].inventors)+"</td>";
        html+ ="</tr></table>";
  $('#popup-meta .popup-content').html(html);
 };

Comment: I suggest using the function to get the string equivalent of html (easier to debug), before inserting it in. Cause im afraid i cant help debug much, seeing as i am currently in the middle of jungle : typing this on an iphone. lol

Comment: @pico.creator, thanks a lot for your help dude.. I don't know why I am getting error on this part only  html+ = "<table border ='1'>"; and I think its correct way..

Comment: try removing the border attribute, you can always add that via a CSS, or jQuery manipulation later. The first goal is to get it to work, not work good straight away =)

Answer (score 0):

I think if you update your request's datatype from jsonp to json then the data object in the response handler should already be parsed, so

```
alert(data.name);
```

should work (if the returned object conforms to your example above)

**EDIT**: this answer based on the OP's indication that the response was json, but response appears to be jsonp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display it just plain text you'll have to convert it. try using http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/

$.toJSON(data)

Answer (score 0):

As such you can't display it using an alert box because as soon as it hits the client it automagically gets turned into a javascript object. Alert is fruitless.

Try instead

```
console.log (data)
```

and have a look at what is in your console window (ie - f12, chrome - ctrl shift j)

Comment: I have updated the question.. In that I have included the JSON response that I am getting as an example just for one ID.

Comment: Does `alert(data.jsonp1308263283961.responseHeader.QTime);` bring any results ( hopefully 3 !!)

Comment: I am getting an error, data.jsonp1308263283961 is undefined
[Break On This Error] alert(data.jsonp1308263283961.responseHeader.QTime);